# How can I subset a dataframe based on time of day in r?

Tags: r, time

I have a large dataset and all I want to do is create another dataset from this based on time of day - so all rows that are between (and including) the times 04:00 and 21:00. The Date column is POSIXlt. A small sample of the dataset is as follows:

| ID | Street | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Saints Road | 2020-12-31 23:00:00 |
| 2 | Saints Road | 2021-01-01 03:00:00 |
| 3 | Saints Road | 2021-01-01 04:00:00 |
| 4 | Saints Road | 2021-07-06 22:00:00 |

Is there a simple way to select rows to produce a dataset that only includes the rows within the aforementioned time range (as in the following example)?

| ID | Street | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Saints Road | 2021-01-01 03:00:00 |
| 3 | Saints Road | 2021-06-01 04:00:00 |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't pandas a **Python** module? Or what do you  mean by *"I attempted with Pandas which seemed like the simplest option but this wasn't compatible with my version of R "* ??

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes that is my understanding but I saw another solution which used Pandas for r., but this is now discontinued in the version of r that I am currently using. I have removed this reference now as it may be confusing matters and obfuscating the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `lubridate`

```
 library(lubridate)
    df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4),Street = c("Saints Road","Saints Road","Saints Road","Saints Road"),Date = c("2020-12-31 23:00:00","2021-01-01 03:00:00","2021-06-01 04:00:00","2021-07-06 22:00:00"))
    df$Date <- as.POSIXlt(df$Date)

df %>% 
  filter(hour(Date) >= 3 & hour(Date) <= 21)
```

Output:

```
 ID      Street                Date
1  2 Saints Road 2021-01-01 03:00:00
2  3 Saints Road 2021-06-01 04:00:00
```